# Speed up UIImagePickerController by using a low res image then later swapping in the high res image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

There is a great wiki about [image loading from the camera picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more).  Which made me aware of costs  of taking an image at full resolution.

At the moment, when a photo is picked, I push a new view controller and display the image at full resolution.  Pushing the view is a really slow and choppy experience (about 1 fps!) that I want to smooth out.  Comparing to picking a photo on Instagram, I notice that they use a low resolution image and later swap in the full image.  (I need the full res image because the user should be able to zoom and pan)

The idea I want is somthing like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{

    UIImage* fullImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // Push a view controller and give it the image.....
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {

    CGSize smallerImageSize = _imageView.bounds;
    UIImage* smallerImage = [MyHelper quickAndDirtyImageResize:_fullImage     
                                                        toSize:smallerImageSize];

    // Set the low res image for now... then later swap in the high res
    _imageView.image = smallerImage;

    // Swap in high res image async
    // This is the part im unsure about... Im sure UIKit isn't thread-safe!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, NULL), ^{
        _imageView.image = _fullImage;
    });
}
```

I think that UIImage isn't memory mapped in until it is used.  Therefore it dons't slow things down until its given to the imageView.  Is this correct?

I think image decoding is already done asynchronously by the system, however, it is sill slowing the phone down considerably while its loading.

Is there a way do perform some of the work required to display an image in a very low priority background queue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to do things the most complicated way :)
Why not just prepare the small image before pushing the view controller and pass it to them? Look at this code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{

    UIImage *fullImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImage *smallImage = [fullImage imageScaledToSize:self.view.bounds];

    // Push a view controller and give it BOTH images
}

// And in your pushed view controller

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _imageView.image = self.smallImage;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    _imageView.image = self.fullImage;
}
```

The main thing is that `viewDidAppear:` will be called right after the animation is done so you can switch images here without any worries.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Ill give it a go this way.  I think that the `imageScaledToSize` method will cause the performance hit anyway since it will have to decompress the UIImage access the byes for the resize.

Comment: Yes, it may have a performance penalty, but it'll be executed before pushing controller so there'll be no low fps animation.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Andrey's answer, instead of using `imageScaledToSize`, use `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex`. In fact, it's very possible (I am pretty sure it's the case) that any image used in the photo album already has a thumbnail. So instead of bothering with the image itself, grab the existing thumbnail and display it, then use Andrey's code to switch in the main image. This way you do as little work as possible during the animation period.

Calling `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` will return the thumbnail image, whether it's already there or needs to be generated. So it'll be quite safe to use, and probably at least as fast as `imageScaledToSize`.

You can find complete code samples to use it in the Apple docs, no need to duplicate it here.

Comment: Great, I will give this a try!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ALAssetsLibrary to load the thumbnail of that image instead of trying to load the image at full resolution? It's faster than resize it as well.

Comment: This actually worked really well, unfortunately there is a location warning when using ALAssets, so it not really worth it for a bit better FPS.

Comment: Location warning? What is happening? If you explain it better I can (maybe :) ) help you. Happy top hear that it works!

Comment: Its a known issue that was fixed in iOS 6.  Basically there is location data in the photo's assets.  The message says the app wants to use your location, whereas it actually just wants access to the photos.  In iOS 6 I have noticed the message has been corrected.